# update tableview swift with UIApplicationDidEnterForeground

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I am having a difficult time getting the following code to work. I want to update a table list when the application wakes up. I verified the data is updated because when I scroll the tableview, it updates. Any help would be appreciated. I do get "attempting reload" and "reloading" in the console.

code in viewdidload():

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadList:", name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object:nil)
```

code in function:

```
func reloadList(notification: NSNotification) {
    println("attempting reloading")

        if (self.tableMain != nil) {
            println("reloading")
            self.tableMain.reloadData()

        }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update your table list in `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)` method. This method will be called every time your view is about to be appeared on the screen.

sample code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      super.viewWillAppear(animated)
      // Do you update here
      self.tableView.reloadData()  
  }
```

If you want to update when your app enter foreground, you can do this:

in your viewController's viewDdiLoad() method

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reloadList:", name: "reloadList", object: nil)
```

In your appDelegate

```
 func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
     NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadList", object: nil)
 }
```

Comment: this is not being called when returning from background.

Comment: @user3896519 please see my edited answer, also, does your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method get called?

Comment: Your edit just calls my function again.    cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Comment: If `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not celled, this is probably your tableView does not set the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`.  You can set them by doing `self.tableView.delegate=self`
and `self.tableView.datasource=self` in your `viewDidLoad()` method.

Comment: sorry, it is being called.

Comment: and if I look at the data being collected in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it is the most current data. It appears it is just the UI not being updated.

Comment: How do you populate the data? You might post your code about retrieve data and the code inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("msgCell") as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel!.text = nameArray[indexPath.row] `

Comment: Unless your `nameArray` get updated after your app back from background, otherwise your cells will still have same values. If your `nameArray` get updated after you getting new data from internet, you should call `tableView.reloadData()` after you finish retrieving data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73707/discussion-between-user3896519-and-ztan).

Answer (score 0):

this code is in objective c you can change the syntax for swift.

add this line in your viewWillAppear function

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadData) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```

and in in viewWillDisappear

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```